# How to typeset 2pii in LaTeX

Tags: amsmath, typography

Using LaTex, how can I typeset 2pii in the following formula (as shown on the [MathJax's home page](https://www.mathjax.org/) but they are using MathML). I tried `2\pii` and `2\pi\i` but, as suspected, that did not work.

[image]

Comment: 2\pi i  ........

Comment: @JPi This one worked (thank you). I noticed you created space between `pi` and `i`. Are there any rules for this that I should be aware of?

Comment: The usual rules for macros. If you add a space the macro has ended, if not the letter counts for the macro name (and `\pii` is not defined).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

TeX and LaTeX macros whose names consist of a backslash character (`\`) followed by *one or more letters* (i.e., `a` thru `z` and `A` thru `Z` -- known in TeX jargon as category-code-`11` characters) -- such as `\pi` -- ***must*** be followed by a non-category-`11` character if TeX is to figure out when the end of the macro's name is reached. Thus, expressions such as `\pi\approx3.14159`, `\pi/2`, `{\pi}i` and `\pi{}i` are valid syntactically, but `\pii` is not.

> How to typeset "2pii" in LaTeX?

The simplest solution is to write `2\pi i`. This is valid because whitespace has category code `10`, not `11`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[f(a)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{\gamma}\frac{f(z)}{z-a}dz\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Blockquote]

Comment: +1. I've taken the liberty of editing your write-up to sharpen the discussion of how TeX can tell when the end of a control word is reached. Feel free to revert if you disagree.

Comment: @Mico, you are in the correct way, your edition is more explanatory than mine. Thanks!